# ARGB in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: icons, adobe-illustrator, transparency, alpha-channel

I need to create some icons and my client's requirements are (A: 0, R:255, G: 255, B: 255) for the background.

**I'm working on Adobe Illustrator, how do I change the Alpha?**

When the background is transparent, all the color values are 0. When the background is white, all the values are 255.

I don't know how to approach this as it's my first time creating icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opacity setting under the appearance tab to change the Transparency.

[image: appearance tab]

Comment: Are you sure? When I'm checking the information, RGB are 0. Thank you for the answer! https://imgur.com/UFVknOX

Comment: Where is that image from? How do you access that information?

Comment: it's from Illustrator. Export > Save for Web > Info at the bottom

Comment: I've never used that option so I can't tell you what that means unfortunately.